# How i x j= k (vector) BUT ixj = (i)(j) (sin90) = (1)(1)(1) = 1 (Scalar)

Tags: vector-spaces, vector-analysis, vector-bundles, vector-fields

How i x j = k (vector) , also in josiah willard Gibbs book who first given the idea of cross product did not explain the mathematical way of cross product. Also from quaternions i found no real conclusion why cross product is vector.

Also i x j = (i)(j)(sin90) (n)
why normal vector (n) comes in this equation is there any mathematical explanation to write normal vector here.

Answer (score 1):

For vectors $A$, $B$, the cross product is defined as
$$A\times B=||A||\cdot||B||\cdot\sin{(\theta)}\cdot n$$
where $n$ is the vector perpendicular to beth $A$ and $B$. This is why the cross product always results in a vector result.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @peter foreman. i want to know why normal vector we add here but it is not the part of our cross product. we have length of two unit vectors and angle between them is 90. Once we apply cos90 we named dot product(scalar), second we apply sin90 we named cross product (scalar) . what is the explanation to write normal vector in cross product.

Comment: That is part of the definition of the cross product.

Comment: Is there any mathematical explanation or any other reason. why we need to apply normal vector a part of our definition in cross product, not need in dot product. For what problem in first place that josiah willard gibbs comes to the solution to apply the idea of normal vector in cross product. Thanks

Comment: @hayatayaz There is no cross product of vectors that is a scalar. The definition of cross product that Peter Foreman gave is correct. Although, he should have mentioned that $\vec n$ must be a unit vector, i.e. $\Vert \vec n \Vert=1$

Comment: Dear @Haris Gusic . You are right this is the part of our definition and length of unit normal is 1 but it has a direction normal to both cross product vectors . i want to know why we need the idea of normal vector in cross product not in dot product. What was the problem which was solved by applying normal vector in cross product. i did not find this answer in books, forum and video lectures even in MIT lectures.

Comment: @hayatayaz There are various applications of the vector cross product in physics. Most notably, it comes up in the definition of the Lorentz force. Also, if you want to calculate the resulting torque when more sources of torque are acting on an object, it is sometimes more convenient to represent torque as the cross product $\vec \tau = \vec r \times \vec F$. The dot product is used for example in the definition of work in physics.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @haris gusic i know the examples of torque and Lorentz force. does it right the idea of normal vector applying in cross product  is the solution to the problem in physics like torques and lorentz force not the solution of the problem in math. And the dot product solution for work done.

Comment: @hayatayaz I am sorry, but I don't know any  strictly mathematical applications that demand that the cross product be defined the way it is. Although, I know that the definition makes it easy to find the cross product using determinants.

Comment: Thanks for math.stackexchange.com and team. I always got reply from experts in this website. If you or other member find any mathematical application or mathematical reason of cross product for which we apply the idea of normal vector in cross product . Pls share.

Answer (score 1):

For quaternionic products, you can also view it as matrix products with the matrices $H^+ (q)$ and $H^-(q)$, as it is shown for example in the book *[Modélisation quaternionique du lien forme-fonction des surfaces articulaires](https://departements.imt-atlantique.fr/iti/publications/index.php?idpublication=18087)* by Guillard, Hamitouche and Roux, ISBN 9782340010468.

As Peter Foreman said before me, the general equation is: $$C = A\times B=||A||\cdot||B||\cdot\sin{(\theta)}\cdot n$$
With $||A||\cdot||B||$ the norm of $C$ and $n$ is the director unit quaternion. You can find the cross product also via a determinant:

$$A \times B =\begin{bmatrix}
  \mathbf{i} & \mathbf{j} & \mathbf{k} \\
  a_1 & a_2 & a_3 \\
  b_1 & b_2 & b_3 \\
\end{bmatrix}$$